# Prevent Expansion of Environment Variables

Tags: c#, .net, environment-variables

I am currently developing an application meant to be an improved environment variables editor for Windows.

I have used both **System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()** and **Registry** to get them. However both methods expands the text between *%*, so instead of getting as instance *%systemroot%/system32* I get *C:/Windows/system32/* in my program.

Is there a way to prevent the expansion of these items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are getting environment variables from the registry - you need to use a special flag: `RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames`.